# Integral inequality $\int_0^1\log \left(f(x)\right)dx\leq \log\left(\int_0^1f(x)dx\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, integral-inequality

How to prove this inequality
$$\int_0^1\log \left(f(x)\right)dx\leq \log\left(\int_0^1f(x)dx\right)$$
for $f>0$.

Comment: Riemann sums and AM-GM.

Comment: Convexity. ${}{}$

Answer (score 8):

$\log$ is concave. this is just Jensen's inequality. See [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) Look at the measure theoretic form.  Please check that this makes sense to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the proof in
https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m218b_09/Lp_and_Sobolev_notes.pdf
on page 3.